# Java string.format overall width with multiple params

Tags: java, printf, string.format

I'm trying to format a string using Java's `String.format`.
I need to create a string like this: `"<padding spaces>  int1 / int2"`.

Right now I have the following format: `" %1$d/%2$d10"` or `"%1$d10/%2$"` (or just `"%1$d/%2$d"`, without the width setting) but this is not working correctly. I want to have the string aligned to the right, with empty spaces as padding for a total width of 10.

I'm using `"%1$10.1f"` elsewhere in my code, for a single float. The double integers need to be padded to the same width.

I have googled my brains out, but am unable to find a way to pad the total string instead of the two individual integers.
Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Pardon my mobile formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the double integer string first using:

```
int one = 1;
int two = 2;
String dints = String.format("%d / %d", one, two);
```

Then format the string `dints` with a width of 10:

```
String whatYouWant = String.format("%10s", dints);
```

Printing `whatYouWant` should output:

```
     1 / 2
```

You can also do it in one call, at the cost of readability, for instance:

```
String whatYouWant = String.format("%10s", String.format("%d / %d", one, two));
```

Or shorter:

```
String whatYouWant = String.format("%10s", one + " / " + two);
```

Comment: So there is no way to do it in one call? Also, I need to use a padding of 9 in the second step for the string to have the same width as the float version. Can you explain why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I updated my answer to address your first question. I'm not exactly sure why you have to use a padding of 9, perhaps you have a space in front of `%10s` whereas I do not. So your format string is `" %10s"` whereas mine is `"%10s"`.

Comment: The bug was indeed somewhere else. Code is working fine